# Android: adding components to RelativeLayout

Tags: android

in My screen, i want to have Hearder(specifically image) on top, and List, and at bottom  i want to have small imagebuttons (like youtube,facebook).

I'm using RelativeLayout.. first two are displaying correctly, last one not display at all on the screen, can anyone help here.

my layout file looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <image></image>
    <ListView></ListView>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <ImageButton></ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your xml code. Its still not visible.

Answer (score 2):

In a `RelativeLayout` it matters in which order you add the child views (since the latter can be bound to the ones added previously).
I think this is the problem in your layout, you have a `fill_parent`/`match_parent` high view already inside (the `ListView`), and there is no room for the footer.

You should change the order of your views inside the `RelativeLayout`:

1. first you should add the header view
   (and bind it to the top: `android:align_parent_top="true"`), then
2. the footer with buttons (and bind it
   to the bottom: `android:align_parent_bottom="true"`), and
3. the `ListView` which should fill up
   the empty space will go in as the
   thirds view, with
   `android:layout_below="header_view"`
   and
   `adroid:layout_above`="footer_view"`

Your layout would then look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout>
    <image android:id="@+id/header" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></image>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <ImageButton></ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@id/header" 
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```